# File (Field) Paths serial token

Tags: 7, tokens, media

I have an image field type configured to accept an unlimited number of values.

Using the File (Field) Paths module I have set the file name field value to `[node:title].[file:ffp-extension-original]`

This is fine if you upload one image because it is renamed to my_node_title.jpg for example.

If you upload several images, they are renamed to my_node_title.jpg, my_node_title_0.jpg, my_node_title_1.jpg, my_node_title_2.jpg and so on.

Is there a token I could use or create that would allow me to add a serial value rather than the default _0, _1, _2? For example my_node_title_a.jpg, my_node_title_b.jpg, my_node_title_c.jpg etc.

I'm looking at the Custom Tokens module at the moment but not having much success.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it starts from 0, isn't it?

If you use that for your path: `[node:title]_a.[file:ffp-extension-original]`

- my_node_title_a0.jpg
- my_node_title_a1.jpg
- my_node_title_a2.jpg

**OR**

You can use the `[file:original:fid]` pattern, it gives serial values but the `fid` increments for all the nodes, not for each nodes. I mean, if you upload 10 images to your first node and then for your second node if you upload 3 images, second node's images' names are as below:

- my_node_title_a11.jpg
- my_node_title_a12.jpg
- my_node_title_a13.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't have used numbers so for clarity I have amended the question.